# PyQt sending parameter to slot when connecting to a signal

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt

I have a taskbar menu that when clicked is connected to a slot that gets the trigger event. Now the problem is that I want to know which menu item was clicked, but I don't know how to send that information to the function connected to. Here is the used to connect the action to the function:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(menuAction, 'triggered()', menuClickedFunc)
```

I know that some events return a value, but triggered() doesn't. So how do I make this happen? Do I have to make my own signal?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use a `lambda`

Here's an example from the [PyQt book](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html):

```
self.connect(button3, SIGNAL("clicked()"),
    lambda who="Three": self.anyButton(who))
```

By the way, you can also use `functools.partial`, but I find the `lambda` method simpler and clearer.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! Totally saved me LOTS of frustration. I should probably get a hold of that book...

Comment: Answer is outdated see Dominique Terrs answer

Answer (score 21):

As already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824311) you can use the lambda function to pass extra arguments to the method you want to execute.

In this example you can pass a string obj to the function AddControl() invoked when the button is pressed.

```
# Create the build button with its caption
self.build_button = QPushButton('&Build Greeting', self)
# Connect the button's clicked signal to AddControl
self.build_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.AddControl('fooData'))
def AddControl(self, name):
    print name
```

Source: [snip2code - Using Lambda Function To Pass Extra Argument in PyQt4](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/12165/)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the previously accepted answer method is now outdated.

Comment: if you are going to pass variables with lambda you should know that lambda will cause a memory leak, if the signal is not properly disconnected (https://stackoverflow.com/q/61871629/5148062) It may be negligible when passing small variables but passing list around could kill your app

Answer (score 5):

I'd also like to add that you can use the `sender` method if you just need to find out what widget sent the signal. For example:

```
def menuClickedFunc(self):
    # The sender object:
    sender = self.sender()
    # The sender object's name:
    senderName = sender.objectName()
    print senderName
```

Answer (score 3):

use functools.partial

otherwise you will find you cannot pass arguments dynamically when script is running, if you use lambda.

Comment: Care to back this up with some evidence?

Comment: You very well can pass arguments dynamically into a created lambda, as lambdas (like normal `def`'ed functions) are closures and thus capture the bindings from their enclosing scope. (Yes, that also implies that as a third option you could use a locally `def`'ed function _and_ dynamically pass parameters to it.) Also, don't forget that you can use default arguments to pass dynamic values to _both_ of them. However, having said that, personally I prefer `functools.partial` as well, my own reason being that it "feels" more lightweight than a `lambda` (without making a claim that it actually is).

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should have each menu item connected to a different slot, and have each slot handle the functionality only for it's own menu item.  For example, if you have menu items like "save", "close", "open", you ought to make a separate slot for each, not try to have a single slot with a case statement in it.

If you don't want to do it that way, you could use the [QObject::sender()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/signalsandslots.html#advanced-signals-and-slots-usage) function to get a pointer to the sender (ie: the object that emitted the signal).  I'd like to hear a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish, though.

Comment: The OP is asking about a perfectly legitimate need. Sometimes many menu items are auto-generated (or just very similar) and should refer to the same slot. There is a standard way to achieve this in PyQt which is recommended in the book and in tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the approaches suggested in other answers,

```
self.whatever.connect(lambda x: self.method(..., x))        # approach 1 (suboptimal)
self.whatever.connect(functools.partial(self.method, ...))  # approach 2 (suboptimal)
```

which is that they create a reference cycle: the `self` object holds a reference to (or is) the object with the signal, which holds a reference to the function or `partial` object, which holds a reference to the `self` object. The result is that (in CPython) none of these objects will be garbage collected when all other references to them disappear; they will only be collected the next time the cycle collector runs. They will in turn keep every other Python data structure that they refer to alive, and whatever Qt objects they collectively own. This is not exactly a memory leak, since everything is freed eventually, but it can be a problem.

There is no reference cycle if you write

```
self.whatever.connect(self.method)
```

because in both PyQt and PySide, `connect` has a special case for Python bound method objects: instead of holding a reference to the bound method, it extracts its two fields (`__self__` and `__func__`) and holds a weak reference to `__self__` and an ordinary reference to `__func__`. If `__self__` goes away, the connection is automatically disconnected.

You can take advantage of that behavior with inline `lambda` functions by writing this:

```
self.whatever.connect((lambda obj, x: obj.method(..., x)).__get__(self))  # approach 1' (better)
```

`__get__` is the method of function objects that creates bound-method objects.

You can make that a little less awkward by writing a replacement for `functools.partial` that returns an object of the correct magical type:

```
def partial_bound_method(bound_method, *args, **kwargs):
    f = functools.partialmethod(bound_method.__func__, *args, **kwargs)
    # NB: the seemingly redundant lambda is needed to ensure the correct result type
    return (lambda *args: f(*args)).__get__(bound_method.__self__)

...

self.whatever.connect(partial_bound_method(self.method, ...))  # approach 2' (better)
```

Here's a test that this works as intended:

```
# replace PyQt5 with PyQt6/PySide2/PySide6 as appropriate
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QCoreApplication
import functools, weakref

def partial_bound_method(bound_method, *args, **kwargs):
    f = functools.partialmethod(bound_method.__func__, *args, **kwargs)
    # NB: the seemingly redundant lambda is needed to ensure the correct result type
    return (lambda *args: f(*args)).__get__(bound_method.__self__)

app = QCoreApplication([])

class Class(QObject):
    def method(*args): pass

def test(maketarget):
    obj = Class()
    # the signal doesn't matter; this is one that happens to exist in QObject
    obj.objectNameChanged.connect(maketarget(obj))
    obj = weakref.ref(obj)
    print('not freed' if obj() else 'freed')

test(lambda obj: obj.method)
test(lambda obj: lambda *args: obj.method('x', *args))
test(lambda obj: functools.partial(obj.method, 'x'))
test(lambda obj: partial_bound_method(obj.method, 'x'))
```

That should print

```
freed
not freed
not freed
freed
```