# How to disconnect a signal from a slot which is a lambda?

Tags: python, pyqt

Suppose the slot takes an argument, e.g.,

```
    self._nam = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager(self)
    # ...
    response = self._nam.get(request)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.on_reply_finished(response))
```

How could the signal be disconnected from the slot? The following gives an error `Failed to disconnect signal timeout().`:

```
    self.timer.timeout.disconnect(lambda: self.on_reply_finished(response))
```

Is it because the lambda isn't a 'real' slot but a Python trick? In that case, how could the response argument be passed to the slot (without making `response` a member)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's because the two lambdas are not the same object.

You need to pass the same reference to the `disconnect` method you used in the `connect` method. If you use an anonymous lambda function, there is no way to disconnect it other then calling `disconnect()` (whithout arguments) on the signal, but that will disconnect **all** connected signals.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you pass same lambda:

```
self._on_timeout = lambda: self.on_reply_finished(response)
self.timer.timeout.connect(self._on_timeout)
# ...
self.timer.timeout.disconnect(self._on_timeout)
```

You may like to append function to timer:

```
self.timer.on_timeout = lambda: self.on_reply_finished(response)
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timer.on_timeout)
# ...
self.timer.timeout.disconnect(self.timer.on_timeout)
```

By the way, you [can use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8824715/1113207) `functools.partial` instead of lambda.

Comment: Please elaborate what would be the benefit of using functools.partial over lambda, in particular if it will prevent signal slot memory leaks as is the case with lambda?

Comment: @Rhdr it won't prevent memory leak, it can be useful for [other reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3252425/1113207).