# How to pass an extra arguments to PyQt slot?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

Hello everyone. I am making simple **model/view application** using python3.4 and PyQt5 in Windows 7.

First of all, here is my code.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QListView
from PyQt5.Qt import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.list = QListView(self)

        model = QStandardItemModel(self.list)

        carMaker = ['Ford', 'GM', 'Renault', 'VW', 'Toyota']

        for maker in carMaker:
            item = QStandardItem(maker)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            model.appendRow(item)
        self.list.setModel(model)

        model.itemChanged.connect(self.on_item_changed)
        #model.itemChanged.connect(functools.partial(self.on_item_changed, item, 1))
        #model.itemChanged.connect(lambda: self.on_item_changed(item, 2))

        self.list.setMinimumSize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Simple modelView")
        self.show()

    def on_item_changed(self, item):
        print(item.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This works fine. But I want to add extra arguments with 'itemChanged' signal. So, I've used lambda and functools

1. lambda

   - changed from 'def on_item_changed(self, item)' to 'def on_item_changed(self, item, num)'
   - changed from 'model.itemChanged.connect(self.on_item_changed)' to 'model.itemChanged.connect(lambda: self.on_item_changed(item, 1))'
   - It has no error. But 'item.text()' shows only 'Toyota'. (maybe last item model)
2. functools.partial

   - changed from 'def on_item_changed(self, item)' to 'def on_item_changed(self, item, num)'
   - changed from 'model.itemChanged.connect(self.on_item_changed)' to 'model.itemChanged.connect(functools.partial(self.on_item_changed, item, 1))'
   - It has no error. But 'item.text()' shows only 'Toyota'. (maybe last item model) Same result as lambda.

*The questions are...*

1. I don't know why lambda and functools shows wrong text.
2. Is any effective way to pass an extra args with signal?

Thank you for read my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question, the problem with `functools.partial` and `lambda` function usage lies in the fact the when you connect the signal to the slot, the variable `item` is set and it references the last `QStandardItem` you added in the `QStandardItemModel`. So basically you are in this situation:

```
def initUI(self):
    self.list = QListView(self)
    model = QStandardItemModel(self.list)
    carMaker = ['Ford', 'GM', 'Renault', 'VW', 'Toyota']

    for maker in carMaker:
        item = QStandardItem(maker) # here you create a item variable that is overwritten
        item.setCheckable(True)     # on every iteration of the for loop
        model.appendRow(item)

    self.list.setModel(model)

    # here you use again the item variable (the same applies for lambda)
    model.itemChanged.connect(functools.partial(self.on_item_changed, item, 1))
```

The reason why it prints "Toyota" is simply the fact that it's the last element in the `carMaker` list, so it's the last `QStandardItem` created, hence the `item` variable references this very object.

To answer the second question instead, you can make use of the `setData()` method of `QStandardItem` to store some data you need in the item, and then retrieve them using `data()`.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QListView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.list = QListView(self)
        model = QStandardItemModel(self.list)
        carMaker = ['Ford', 'GM', 'Renault', 'VW', 'Toyota']
        index = 0 # just to store something different for each QStandardItem

        for maker in carMaker:
            item = QStandardItem(maker)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            item.setData(index, Qt.UserRole + 1)
            model.appendRow(item)
            index += 1

        self.list.setModel(model)

        model.itemChanged.connect(self.on_item_changed)

        self.list.setMinimumSize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Simple modelView")
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot('QStandardItem')
    def on_item_changed(self, item):
        print("%s - %s" % (item.text(), item.data(Qt.UserRole + 1)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Alternatively you can make use of a signal mapper as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824311/how-to-pass-arguments-to-callback-functions-in-pyqt).

Comment: Thank you Daniele Pantaleone!. You suggested great solution. But your code's result looks something wrong. 'item.data()' shows only None. Not a incremental number. Can you teach me why?

Comment: I have changed the 'item.setData(index, Qt.userRole) to 'item.setData(index, Qt.userRole + 1)' and item.data(Qt.UserRole + 1). This works as I expected. Now, It is clear what are setData(), data(), Qt.UserRole. Thanks again. Daniele Pantaleone.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the issue. I update my answer with the correction in case someone else need it ;)