# python pyQt4 listWidget passing extra arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qlistwidget

I am having a problem with the .itemClicked() method in PyQt4.

When I use it regularly Ex:

```
 listObj.itemClicked.connect(some_function)
```

I can use it in a function

```
def some_function(self,ITEM):
```

but I tried pass in another argument with the partial function from functools

```
listObj.itemClicked.connect( partial(some_function, extra_argument) )
```

and it replaces the ITEM with the extra_argument.

I also tried using the lambda function

```
listObj.itemClicked.connect(lambda: some_function(item, extra_argument))
```

this would work but it would return a tuple that would be stuck on my first item that I clicked.

Ex.

```
def some_function(self, ITEM, extra_argument):
    str(Item[0].text) # this would return a tuple with the second item 
                      # empty.
```

I checked around but all I could find was passing extra arguments on a button.

Thank you,

[How to pass an extra arguments to PyQt slot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718448/how-to-pass-an-extra-arguments-to-pyqt-slot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use it as follows:

```
extra_argument = {your value}
listObj.itemClicked.connect(lambda item, extra_argument= extra_argument: self.some_function(item, extra_argument))

def some_function(self, item, extra_argument):
    [...]
```

Or you can use partial but the default argument should be at the end:

```
listObj.itemClicked.connect(partial(self.some_function, extra_argument))

def some_function(self, extra_argument, item):
    [...]
```

Comment: Thank you so Much! This solved the problem in the most elegant way possible. This finally solves all my problems.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't connect a two-argument slot to a one-argument signal.  It just doesn't make any sense to do that.  Qt won't be able to supply a value for the extra argument.

Of course you can write a Python function to receive the one-argument signal, attach a second argument to it, and call a **second** function.  That's what you were trying to do when you attempted to use lambda, which passes a one-argument function to Qt but issues a two-argument function call within your program.  This is how you do that:

```
listObj.itemClicked.connect(lambda item: some_function(item, extra_argument))
```

But check the link you supplied to see the pitfalls with this approach.  Be sure you want a lambda expression and not a closure.  This would be the closure approach:

```
def get_handler(self, extra):
    def h(item):
        some_function(item, extra)
    return h

listObj.itemClicked.connect(get_handler(extra_argument))
```

I find that I need to use closures occasionally with Qt callbacks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I initially tried to do something like this, but yours worked.