# Getting Information Which QLabel Clicked in PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel

I have a list of QLabel and want to learn which QLabel clicked . When i look for the making QLabel clickable , this code has worked :

```
 labels[i].mousePressEvent = self.print_some
 def print_some(self, event):
    print("Clicked")
```

But I didn't figure out  which object clicked . How can i do that ?

Comment: This is pretty similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/8824311/2997179

Comment: @MartinValgur you are right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily make custom receivers for events, which would contain the event source information:

```
import functools

labels[i].mousePressEvent = functools.partial(self.print_some, source_object=labels[i])

def print_some(self, event, source_object=None):
    print("Clicked, from", source_object)
```

Comment: This is a good solution but the `event` and `source_object` need to be swapped in the method signature.

Comment: I have tried and prints 'Clicked from  <PyQt4.QtGui.QMouseEvent object at 0x0000000002CE1E58>'  this . When i want to print label text like ' functools.partial(self.print_some, labels[i].text()) ' also prints same above . How to receive label attributes ?

Comment: I fixed the code - the second argument to the function has to be a keyword argument, check it now