# Passing argument to PyQt SIGNAL connection

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots, qmenu, qaction

Is it possible to pass an argument to PyQt4 Signal connections? In my case I have *n* buttons with set the same menu dinamically created on the interface, depending on user's input:

```
for j in range(0, len(self.InputList)):

    arrow = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
    arrow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 40*(j+3)+15, 19, 23))

    menu = QtGui.QMenu(Form)
    for element in SomeList:
        cb = QtGui.QRadioButton(element,menu)
        ca = QtGui.QWidgetAction(menu)
        ca.setDefaultWidget(cb)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(cb,QtCore.SIGNAL("stateChanged(int)"),self.SomeFunction)
    arrow.setMenu(menu)
```

Although the menu is the same for all the buttons into the interface, the user should be able to select a value from any of the buttons and, for any of them, the action is the same ("add the selected value to a line edit") with the only difference that the line edit might be the *1st* as well as the *2nd*, the *3rd*.

What I would like to ask, then, is if there's any way to pass an argument *j* here:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(cb,QtCore.SIGNAL("stateChanged(int)"),self.SomeFunction(j))
```

**EXAMPLE**:

At this execution the user's inputs are 3, so I will have 3 line edits and three push buttons with the same menu:

```
Line Edit 1:
Line Edit 2:
Line Edit 3:
```

Using the same function `SomeFunction`, I'd like to edit the value of the Line Edits. So if the user is touching the menu attached to the 2nd line edit, the function `SomeFunction` shall be called with the argument 2 `SomeFunction(2)`, so the same method will understand itself which Line Edit is the right one:

```
Line Edit 1:
Line Edit 2: modified
Line Edit 3:
```

I need this because the number of Line Edits on the main window depends on what the user is selecting. I'm a newbie and so far I've always created one function for any object into the GUI, but this time the number is dynamic and I'm sure there are some more elegant ways to create this kind of signal connections, that I have not understood though so far from my documentations reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different approach: instead of attaching the data as an argument to the signal handler, attach it to the menu-item itself. This offers much greater flexibility, because the data is not hidden inside an anonymous function, and so can be accessed by any part of the application.

It is very easy to implement, because Qt already provides the necessary APIs. Here is what your example code would look like if you took this approach:

```
        for j in range(0, len(self.InputList)):

            arrow = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
            arrow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 40*(j+3)+15, 19, 23))

            menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
            group = QtGui.QActionGroup(menu)
            for element in SomeList:
                action = menu.addAction(element)
                action.setCheckable(True)
                action.setActionGroup(group)
                action.setData(j)
            arrow.setMenu(menu)

            group.triggered.connect(self.SomeFunction)

    def SomeFunction(self, action):
        print(action.data())
```

Comment: I think we are incredibly close to the solution. Sorry, I'm a newbie, but after implementing your solution I'm being able to pass this element to the function: `print action.data()` -> `<PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant object at 0x00000000086FD4C0>`. How can I retrieve the string value `element` that I attached to the menu, something like `action.text()`?

Comment: I'm asking this because when debugging the script I'm not seeing any string text into the object `action`. Say that I have `SomeList = ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']`, what I'd need is that when the action `option2` is pressed into one of the menus attached to the buttons, the corresponding line edit should acquire the value `option2`. So what I have thought is to define `SomeFunction` to set the `text()` of the line edit to `option2`, and the reason of passing the argument is to communicate the software which one of the several line edits in the main window is the right one.

Comment: Never mind, it was a stupid spelling mistake (`.Text()` rather than `.text()`) and I have thought it was a missing attribute. Your solution works amazingly with `action.text()`, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, sorry for bothering you but I'm not being able to find where the information `j` is stored into the object `action`. When I do this: `action.setData(j)`, where can I retrieve the `j` value from the object `action` after calling it into the function `SomeFunction`?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ. From `action.data()`. If you're using Python2, this will return a `QVariant` by default. To convert this to a python object, do `j = action.data().toPyObject()`.

Answer (score 2):

Be advised that you are using a deprecated version of SIGNAL/SLOT implementation in PyQt that [has been removed in PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#old-style-signals-and-slots) (and even its current implementation in PyQt4 is somewhat buggy).

If possible, I would change the SIGNAL/SLOT syntax in your code.

The way the new Signal/Slot mechanism works is this:

```
class Worker(QThread):
    stateChanged = Signal(int)

    ....

    def some_method(self):
        self.stateChanged.emit(1)
```

In the GUI thread, you would similarly have something like this (assuming `worker = Worker()` is defined somewhere:

```
class GUI(QDialog)

    worker = Worker()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.worker.stateChanged.connect(self.my_desired_method)

    def my_desired_method(self, param):
        print param #prints out '1'
```

Of course, this code wouldn't work "out of the box", but it's a general concept of how Signals/Slots should be handled in PyQt (and PySide).

Comment: Thanks, I've heard already it is a deprecated version but unfortunately it's too hard to change the code right now cause I need to slightly change the structure to the project that is not mine. Can't mark your answer but definitely +1 for the useful tip I'm gonna use from next project ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help.

```
self.op = "point"
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.radioButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(bool)"),lambda : self.anyButton(self.radioButton.isChecked(),self.op))

def anyButton(self,kol,vv):
    print kol
    print vv
```

The output is

```
>>> 
True
point
```

you can take a look at this : [PyQt sending parameter to slot when connecting to a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940555/pyqt-sending-parameter-to-slot-when-connecting-to-a-signal)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I have tried this method but it seems there is a problem. As I wrote above, I am in a `for` loop which is creating `j in range(0,n)` menus (although any of them has the same list of radio buttons). What happens, though, is that the output is always `n`. So basically although I pass `QtCore.QObject.connect(cb, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(bool)"),lambda : self.SomeFunction(cb.isChecked(),j)) `, the function is always called with `j == n`. It seems is overriding the previous `j = 0,1,...n-1` values, any idea why?

Comment: The value of `j` used is the value of `j` when the lambda function is called, not the value of `j` when the lambda function is defined. See this post for solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510860/qtcore-qobject-connect-in-a-loop-only-affects-the-last-instance