# Extra arguments on customContextMenuRequest connect call

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have an unusual case of needing to pass an extra argument when defining a connection to a `customContextMenuRequested` slot in PyQt.

Of course, the basic command is usually done in the form of:

```
myListWidget.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
myListWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect( self.Whatever_Popup )
```

I'm also aware and often use both the lambda and `functools.partial`
methods to pass extra arguments to other general functions.
However, I have a case where I need to pass a `QObject` (`listWidget` in this case) when defining the connection.

The receiving function is structured like so:

```
def Whatever_Popup(self, pos):
    globalPos = self.mapToGlobal(pos)
    globalPos.setX( globalPos.x() + 720)
    globalPos.setY( globalPos.y() + 115)

    menu = QtGui.QMenu()
    menu.addAction("Edit")

    selectedItem = menu.exec_(globalPos)

    if selectedItem:
        if selectedItem.text() == "Edit":
            print "Here"
            #self.DoEdit(widget)
```

I've tried all the following but with no joy.

```
myListWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect( partial(self.Whatever_Popup, newLst))

myListWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect( partial(self.Whatever_Popup, QtCore.QPoint, newLst))

myListWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect( partial(self.Whatever_Popup, QtCore.SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)"), newLst))

myListWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect( lambda: self.Whatever_Popup, (QtCore.SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)"), newLst) )
```

All return an error. Am I close? or is this perhaps not possible? which would be a bit surprising.

`myListWidget` is generated dynamically btw.  I need to pass some reference
to the `listWidget` because `self.DoEdit(widget)` will need it for further processing.  Can't pre-define the name and retrieve it in `self.DoEdit` since it's created dynamically.
Does anyone have a solution to this?
Thanks to all in advance,

Comment: ahh..this is related, testing now...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856614/passing-argument-to-pyqt-signal-connection

Comment: Why `partial` doesn't work?

Comment: lol, wish I knew ;-)  Doing a                      myListWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect( partial(self.Whatever_Popup, QtCore.SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)"), myListWidget)) returns TypeError: QWidget.mapToGlobal(QPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'

Comment: You don't need to put the second argument, it will be passed automatically by Qt. Just `partial(self.Whatever_Popup, myListWidget)`.

Comment: btw,..why does this "add comment" area not respect carriage return?

Comment: right, sorry,..I did a version without "pos" and it too errors

Comment: `myListWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect( partial( self.Whatever_Popup, myListWidget) )` returns `TypeError: QWidget.mapToGlobal(QPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QListWidget'`

Comment: Just like this: `myListWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(partial(self.Whatever_Popup, new_argument))`

Comment: just to clarify, the receiving function is defined as         
    def Whatever_Popup(self, pos, widget):

Comment: apologies, cdonts,..please see my edited comment just before yours...

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a working example:

```
from functools import partial

from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QObject
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QListWidget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.list_widget = QListWidget(self)
        self.list_widget.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        my_object = QObject()
        self.list_widget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(
            partial(self.receiver, my_object))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.list_widget)

    def receiver(self, my_object, pos):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Replace `my_object` with whatever you need.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on the answer,...have to rearrange the receiving functions arguments like so:

before:

```
def Whatever_Popup(self, pos, widget):
```

after:

```
def Whatever_Popup(self, widget, pos):
```

Comment: Well, at the same time buddy!